# Not seeing all data received through TCP

Tags: c#, xml, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm trying to receive data with a socket that I use as a TCP Client but somehow not all data that is being shown in WireShark is available in my code.

With WireShark I can see the incoming packets and the test tool (not made by me) shows the data the way I expect it.

When I print the length of `recData` in the example below, it correlates with the length of the data as seen in WireShark so everything seems to be fine so far.

However, When I want to show the received message as a readable string (UTF-8 encoded XML) I can only see a part of the messages that I expect.

The `Socket` I use:

```
            private Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        private byte[] _recieveBuffer = new byte[1024];

        public void Connect()
        {
            try
            {
                sock.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(this.IpAddress), this.Port));
                sock.ReceiveBufferSize = _recieveBuffer.Length;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { }

            sock.BeginReceive(_recieveBuffer, 0, _recieveBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);

        }

        private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            int received = sock.EndReceive(ar);

            if (received <= 0)
                return;

            byte[] recData = new byte[received];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(_recieveBuffer, 0, recData, 0, received);

            if (onDataReceived != null)
                onDataReceived(this, new MyNewEventargs(recData));

            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recData));

            sock.BeginReceive(_recieveBuffer, 0, _recieveBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);                
        }
```

The packets I receive:
[image]

What I noticed is that the second received package (the one highlighted in the image) is about twice the size of the first package.

When I look at the contents of the packages I can see that the first one contains 1 complete XML item and the second one contains 2.

However, when I print the contents of the second package to a string I still only see one XML item so the third one is lost.

the complete XML message that I expect looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Xml>
<Element1 Attirbute1="First item" Attirbute2="0" Attirbute3="0" Attirbute4="0" Attirbute5="0">
    <Element2 Attirbute1="600" Attirbute2="1" Attirbute3="bla"/>
</Element1>
</Xml>
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Xml>
<Element1 Attirbute1="Second item" Attirbute2="0" Attirbute3="0" Attirbute4="0" Attirbute5="0">
    <Element2 Attirbute1="600" Attirbute2="1" Attirbute3="bla"/>
</Element1>
</Xml>
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Xml>
<Element1 Attirbute1="Third item" Attirbute2="0" Attirbute3="0" Attirbute4="0" Attirbute5="0">
    <Element2 Attirbute1="600" Attirbute2="1" Attirbute3="bla"/>
</Element1>
</Xml>
```

The XML message that the Console shows looks like this:

```
//First package
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Xml>
<Element1 Attirbute1="First item" Attirbute2="0" Attirbute3="0" Attirbute4="0" Attirbute5="0">
    <Element2 Attirbute1="600" Attirbute2="1" Attirbute3="bla"/>
</Element1>
</Xml>

//First item of second package
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Xml>
<Element1 Attirbute1="Second item" Attirbute2="0" Attirbute3="0" Attirbute4="0" Attirbute5="0">
    <Element2 Attirbute1="600" Attirbute2="1" Attirbute3="bla"/>
</Element1>
</Xml>
```

As you can see the third XML item is lost.

I tried messing around with threads ans stopwatches to see if it is a timing issue but since the size of the received packages is correct I don't think this is the cause of my problem.

When I print the received `byte[]` to the Console, I haven't done any deserialization yet.

How can I get this socket to receive (or enable me to see) all the data that is sent?

---

EDIT:

After some more debugging I saw that I do seem to get all the data but I think something goes wrong with the `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recData)`.

the second time `ReceiveCallback` is called, the received bytes count is 446 instead of 221. The data is copied to the byte[] `recData` and it does hold 446 bytes. When I put a breakpoint on this line and manually change the int `received` to 221 (so it will only copy the first item to the byte[]) I get the same result as when it stays on 446.

So I do get all the data but somehow it doesn't decode into the string I expect.

Hope this makes sense..

Comment: I think there is a race condition in your code, if you receive data while you're still in ReceiveCallback it will not trigger another call to the callback.

Comment: Can you show the sending method?

Comment: @neuhaus why? TCP sockets have internal buffers.

Comment: @Jeroen van Langen I don't have access to the sources of the server.

Comment: @PavelMayorov because the event may be triggered while there is no event handler for it.

Comment: He's missing the last message, not the first.. so it doesn't have anything to do with the eventhandler.

Comment: @neuhaus what event are you talking about?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I was thinking perhaps the last message gets lost

Comment: Is there any way to elaborate my question so I can help get to an answer?

Answer (score 0):

What´s your "onDataReceived" doing? Anything that could affect your logic?

Your code works here without a hitch (testing with generic HTML at least), all bytes received and shown, apart from the event handler mentioned above.

(NOTE: can´t post comments, that´s why I´m posting a reply. Feel free to delete.)

C.

Comment: At the moment the 'OnDataReceived' only deserializes the message and prints it to a textbox. When I remove it I only get the very first package and when I test with a `thread.sleep(50);` I see the two packages again as described in the original question. Could it be a timing issue after all?

Comment: So the event handler is altering the result somehow, and perhaps the data itself is fishy... Maybe you could post the event handler code and the raw bytes of the 2 packets received?